# Syntax error in insert into statement - in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

I am trying to insert a record into MS Access db, with the below code. I have used the same type of code several times in my project. But I dont know why it is erroring , saying that there is a syntax error. Some one please suggest me where the code is wrong.

```
Try
                If MainForm.con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    MainForm.con.Open()
                End If
                Dim cmdText As String
                cmdText = "insert into tblBottling(bottlingDate,workerName,seed,size,noOfBottles,timeTaken,remarks) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, MainForm.con)

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bottlingDate", botDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yy"))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workerName", workerCB.SelectedItem.ToString)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seed", seedCB.SelectedItem.ToString)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", botSizeCB.SelectedItem.ToString)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noOfBottles", CInt(noOfBot.Text))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeTaken", timeTakenTxt.Text)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", remarksTxt.Text)

                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MainForm.con.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Size** is a reserved keyword for MS-Access. If you want to use that word as column name then you should always enclose it between square brackets

```
cmdText = "insert into tblBottling
          (bottlingDate,workerName,seed,[size],noOfBottles,timeTaken,remarks) 
          values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`cmdText = "insert into tblBottling([bottlingDate],[workerName],[seed],[size],[noOfBottles],[timeTaken],[remarks]) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

> Please always use  square brackets for your columns  incase of such error.
>
> Because you cannot memorise all the keywords.
>
> Good Luck